# Date-time in openapi specification not working as expected with DateTimeFormat annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, date

I have open api specification in spring boot application which generates me,

OpenAPI:

```
 lastCommunicated:
       type: string
       format: date-time
       example: '2023-06-29T04:49:38Z'
```

EmployeeDTO.java

```
  private Long id;
  
  private String name;

  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
  private OffsetDateTime lastCommunicated;
```

Request JSON:

```
{
 "id": 1,
"name": "test",
 "lastCommunicated":"2021-08-31T01:03:34Z"

}
```

Response:

```
{
 "id": 1,
"name": "test",
 "lastCommunicated":1630371814.000000000

}
```

I need "lastCommunicated":"2021-08-31T01:03:34Z" format.

Answer (score 0):

This date `2021-08-31T01:03:34Z` represents the `ISO_INSTANT` [format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT). So you can use the [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) instead of `OffsetDateTime`

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", timezone = "UTC")
private OffsetDateTime lastCommunicated;
```

And also you jackson [@JsonFormat](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) with providing the format for serialization and deserialization.